# structure identifier is not defined even though it is

Tags: c, object, struct, declaration, typedef

I have a school project where I have to make my structures and functions in a .h header file.

I've created my structure but cannot use any of the variables within it as whenever I call it it highlights the structure name and tells me its not defined even though it clearly is in my structure and doesn't highlight or give me any syntax errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct test1 {
    int array1[3];
    int array2[3];
};

int main(void) {
    scanf_s(" %d %d", &test1.array1[1], &test1.array2[1]);

}
```

I have tried using typedef with and without and its the same result. if I create individual variables outside the structure I get no issues so i believe its some issue with how I'm creating my structures but I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: You haven't created any instances of `struct test1`. The `typedef` is also pointless since you don't give it a name.

Comment: Your typedef is incomplete.  If you write `typedef int foo;`, you have defined `foo`.  If you write `typedef int;`, you have defined nothing; it's just a syntax error.  Simillarly for `typedef struct test1 {};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `typedef` makes me think that you actually want to define a type named `test1`. Move the name to after the `struct`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int array1[3];
    int array2[3];
} test1;            // now a name you can use
```

You then need to create an instance of `test1` to be able to use it with `scanf_s`:

```
int main(void) {
    test1 t1;      // `t1` is now a `test1` instance

    scanf_s(" %d %d", &t1.array1[1], &t1.array2[1]);
//                     ^^             ^^
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared type specifier `struct test1` (and moreover the typedef declaration does not even declare a typedef name for the type specifier `struct test1`)

```
typedef struct test1 {
    int array1[3];
    int array2[3];
};
```

But the call of `scanf_s`

```
scanf_s(" %d %d", &test1.array1[1], &test1.array2[1]);
```

expects objects. `test1` is not an object. This name is not even declared.

You could write for example

```
struct test1 test1;
scanf_s(" %d %d", &test1.array1[1], &test1.array2[1]);
```